# Testing .NET application throughout multiple Versions of Windows

Tags: sql, windows, silverlight, wcf, testing

I have built a Silverlight\WCF\Sql application and as a part of the testing i need to validate that the application will work across multiples permutations of Windows\IIS\SQL\IE
 (Client SL and Server WCF\SQL)

Eg
Windows Server XXXX with IIS Y.Y  on SQL ZZZZ

I know that common sense says that the application should work in the plataforms supported by Siverlight\WCF\SQL, BUT nervertheless we need to perform those tests.

Is there another way of doing this testing "easily"? and by easily i mean not creating a bunch of virtual machines.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you install all iterations of IIS and SQL on each Windows Server machine side-by-side?  You would need at the very least as many VM's as versions of Windows you want to test.

Comment: Short of "already have all the environments you need set up", I'm not sure what to suggest. How do you test against various combinations of OS/Server software without... having virtual or physical environments that contain that software?

Comment: Thanks for your answare.  I'm not sure if you can have different versions of IIS in the same Windows, I'm googling it

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/t/1157878.aspx nope, no multiple versions of iis on the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say in your comment there is a dependency between IIS and Windows versions.

There are tools that allow you to run multiple versions of IE. But this will not test different versions of Silverlight.

But for the server side stuff you cannot get around creating VMs. But with a bit of planning you can minimise the number that you need.

Create:

- Client machines f.eks SL 3 and SL4
- App layer machines f.eks II6 and II7
- Database layer machines f.eks SQL 2005 and 2008

Then by varying the config and you can test different combinations.